# How to have a specific distance from the bottom of the page while the height is responsive for a div

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

}

Currently I am creating a chatbot and the chat input section when the height change sometimes it gets disappears that it get out of the screen or when a phone screen is big it shows the input above from the required position. I have tried vh and percentage method but it is not working

```
.chat-input
{
width: 304px;
height: 34px;
z-index: 1;
margin-bottom: 34px;
position:relative;
top:calc(10vh);
background-color: #F3F3F3;
border-radius: 50px;
}
```

For refrence
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iogKf.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzRpD.png)

Just I Want it should have some specific distance between the chat input and the bottom of the screen which should be the same for example a margin of 15px.

Answer (score 0):

use position fixed, dont combine vh units with top

```
.chat-input {
    width: 304px;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed; /* Change from relative to fixed */
    bottom: 15px;    /* Distance from the bottom of the screen */
    left: 50%;       /* Center the input horizontally */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Adjust for exact centering */
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```